# The way to develop Ruby on Rails framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make some tiny patches to Ruby on Rails. Previously I've directly edited the gems installed in my machine (e.g. `\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\activerecord-4.2.0`), while knowing it would be a pretty bad way. And I'm still not sure how to tweak, test and run the framework efficiently, even after walking through [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html) and [rails-dev-box](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box/blob/master/README.md)

What's the concept of rails-dev-box is? Is it just supposed to bring a way to run a minitest via in the environment that the Rails core team also uses? Are we supposed to modify/add/delete codes, write a test corresponding the change in the host machine, and then run the test in the guest machine?

It even doesn't have Rails at all, so while it claims an app running in the guest machine can be accessed from the host machine, we even can't make and run a Rails app without manually installing it from somewhere.

The workflow I'd rather expect was...

1. Clone the Rails repository into the local disk.
2. Change the local Rails codes.
3. Run the framework based on the code I've just edited.
4. Run the test in the same environment as theirs.

and the rails-dev-box seems to lack the 3rd condition, unless I'm missing something...

I know we can specify the location of Rails itself in Gemfile, like

```
gem 'rails', :path => '/vagrant/rails'
```

But not certain that's the workaround (at least, I can't test the rails app generator by my codes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the concept of rails-dev-box is?

To provide a common base for everyone developing for Rails that includes all the databases, ruby, execjs, etc.

> Is it just supposed to bring a way to run a minitest via in the environment that the Rails core team also uses?

Yes, as well as the other dependencies needed for testing your changes properly. Prior to this dev box build many **MANY** pull requests had to be rejected because the author hadn't tested thoroughly eg. because they didn't have one of the DB engines installed, or had an older version of ruby. This dev box gives a standard environment that the Rails core team keeps up to date.

> Are we supposed to modify/add/delete codes, write a test corresponding the change in the host machine, and then run the test in the guest machine?

Yes, [as detailed here](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box/blob/master/README.md#recommended-workflow) on the dev box README you linked to in your question.

> It even doesn't have Rails at all.

No, of course not, otherwise you'd have to use the VM's editing tools to edit your code, this is also covered [in great detail here](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box/blob/master/README.md#recommended-workflow) in the dev box README that you linked to in your question. It has step by step instructions on cloning your fork of rails, and what the VM does to map that volume etc.

> Run the framework based on the code I've just edited.

Based on your comment about the Gemfile I'm guessing that you wanted to create a Rails app based on your changes? You can, of course, do this if you wish - just as you've detailed with the `:path` option (that is **the way** to do what you want), but this is not a normal process.

Comment: Agree with everything but the last bit - you'd have to be pretty ballsy to make a change that you had never tried in a rails app.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the change, and honestly I don't know what other contributors do.

Comment: @smathy thanks for clarification, much appreciated, but I still have to wonder, if the virtual machine doesn't have Rails at all, how to run `bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0` in the guest machine as the instruction claims?

Comment: You would create a local app on your own machine, then point the rails gem to the mapped vagrant share as you have done in your question, and then you'd run the `rails s` on your local machine.